# python.org tutorial list+map example error

Tags: python, list, callable

tutorial example code error operate!

very confuse~~

type(list) is list

i know that callable is class or function

```
squares = list(map(lambda x: x**2, range(10)))
```

---

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 squares = list(map(lambda x: x**2, range(10)))

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

How can i fix it?

Comment: You probably created a variable called `list` - common mistake; it overrides the built-in `list` type.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are using the list variable before running this command.
Please exit with CTRL + d and try again.

Comment: "try again"? :) Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please be sure to either convert this post into a comment when you get commenting privilege, or to turn it into a qualified answer (see [answer] for guidance)

Answer (score -1):

In python, a list is a data structure and therefore a key word. Words like "list" cannot be used as a name for a function, variable, etc. Try changing the name of the function to something else!